# Built in encode/decode function with support for keys, other than mcrypt

Tags: php

Does php has any built-in function for encoding and decoding a string, I want it very simple, mcrypt does the job but still I dont need top of class encryption.Other than urlencode()

Comment: What kind of encoding do you want? `urlencode` has a very different purpose than `mcrypt`. Also, what problem are you trying to solve? It sounds like `mcrypt` does what you want, but you don't want to use it for some reason. What reason is that?

Comment: 1) What's wrong with mcrypt? 2) `urlencode()` is encoding, not encryption.

Comment: how about [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)?

Comment: thats why I specially mentioned about urlencode() somebody mentioned it when I asked this question somewhere else. I need simple encryption for passing user_id in activation link  to user email as mcrypt generates really long string sometimes. So I need a less aggressive encryption function .

Comment: For an activation link, a simpler solution is to just generate a random number and save it in your database (linked to the user account somehow), then send it out in an email. That way, there's no way for an attacker to guess the activation link, and it doesn't require any complicated security (since there's no link between the two numbers except in your database).

Comment: See: [Nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)

Comment: I am sending a random string also, sending three parameters encrypted user_id, random md5 generated string, salt md5 hashed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [OpenSSL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php)

```
$key = file_get_contents('keyfile');
openssl_private_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $key);
openssl_private_decrypt($data, $decrypted, $key);
```